# Changing the href attribute in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have one bootstrap modal that I change the contents of for 9 different elements (depending on what the user clicks on).
 Currently I am able to change the title and description area of each modal but i'm having trouble changing the `href=""` attribute of the modal.

Here is my html modal code,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#">Visit Site</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the img that the user clicks on to activate the modal (I have 9 in total)

```
<img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Project 1"
    data-description="This is the description for Project 1" src="source of my image">
```

And JQuery

```
$("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data("whatever");
    var info = button.data("description");

    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find(".modal-title").text(recipient);
    modal.find(".modal-body p").text(info);
});
```

So my JQuery extracts the data-whatever and data-description from the img and inserts them into the modal with my JQuery. I have not been able to find a way to target the href attribute of the "Visit Site" link in the bootstrap modal code. I tried adding a new data-link with my desired url but that just changes the text and does not set the actual link.

Also, I would like to add an image to the modal that varies based on which image the user clicks on to activate the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```js
$("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
 var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
 var recipient = button.data("whatever");
 var info = button.data("description");
 var link = button.data("href");
 var img_src = button.attr("src");
 var modal = $(this);
 modal.find(".modal-title").text(recipient);
 modal.find(".modal-body p").text(info);
 modal.find(".modal-body img").attr("src", img_src);
 modal.find(".modal-footer button a").attr("href", link);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Modal</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Project 1" data-description="This is the description for Project 1" data-href="https://www.google.com" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg">

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div>
                            <img src="" height="200px" width="200px" />
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#">Visit Site</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use attr() for change href. Please follow below example, it may help you.

```
$("a").attr("href","https://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image.jpg data-title="Title one" data-desc="Description one" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" />

<img src="image.jpg data-title="Title two" data-desc="Description two" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"/>

<img src="image.jpg data-title="Title three" data-desc="Description three" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"/>
```

jQuery

```
$('img[data-target="#exampleModal"]').on('click', function() {

    var title = $(this).data('title');

    var desc = $(this).data('desc');

    $('#exampleModal .modal-title').html(title);

    $('#exampleModal .modal-body').html(desc);

  });

})
```